# How to properly show depth

Tags: adobe-photoshop, critique

I'm trying to design a DIP chip with my name on it. I think the chip itself is pretty good, the texture is there, the text is nicely grainy, and the little circle is nicely depressed. However, I'm having a much harder time with the metal pins coming out of the chip. Do you guys have any suggestions on how to improve this?

Here is the image itself:

[image]

The chip should have a thickness to it, as I have tried to create here. The thickness is okay, it could be better, but my real issue is with the metal pins that come out, and that is what this question is about.

Thank you for any advice!

After reading @user287001's advice, It became a lot easier to produce something more realistic. Thank you for your help! Here's what ended up happening to the pins:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layer style Bevel&Emboss adds an illusion of depth. It should be applied to IC body, too for consistent looks

[image]

[image]

The upper row of pins could be a little higher. This way, (a little exaggerated)

[image]

(Copied the lower row and inverted it Image > Adjustments > Invert) before the embossing. The rows have individual brightness and contrast to make them even.

Comment: Your advice with the bevel and emboss helped a lot with the pins. I ended up not adding it to the chip, but the final result was pleasing to me. I updated the question to show my progress. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Bevel & emboss styles for corners. You can also use shadow for better results.

Comment: Hi Deepak, thanks for your answer. We're a very visual community, so we like long answers with screenshots. Could you substantiate how bevel & emboss and shadows would work and how they could improve the result?